# Completely stuck on where I'm going wrong in my class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I need to run up a score based on number of questions answered correctly between two players.

I tried to shoehorn a way into the ask() function inside the class, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I thought setting the variable after the question based on the answer, and then sending it out to the game would work, but clearly I'm wrong

```
    import random
    PLAYER_1_SCORE = 0
    PLAYER_2_SCORE = 0
    TURN = 0

class Question():
    def __init__(self, question, answer, options, score):
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        self.options = options
        self.score = score

    def ask(self,):
        print (self.question + '?')
        for n, option in enumerate(self.options):
            print ('%d) %s' % (n + 1, option))

        choice = int(input())   # answers are integers
        if choice == self.answer:
            score = 1
            self.score = score
        else:
            score = 0
            self.score = score

    def get_score(self):
      return score

questions = [
  #1
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),
  #1                   
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),
  #3                   
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),
  #4                  
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),
  #5                   
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),
  #6                   
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),
  #7                   
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),

  #8
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),                   
  #9                     
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),
  #10 
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),
    ]

random.shuffle(questions) 

def player_1():
  for question in questions:
      question.ask()
      PLAYER_1_SCORE += question.get_score

def player_2():
  for question in questions:
      question.ask()
      score = Question.get_score()
      PLAYER_2_SCORE += score

def game_round():
  while TURN < 10:
    player_1()
    player_2()
    TURN += 1

def main():
  play_again = 'Y'
  if play_again == 'Y':
    game_round
    if PLAYER_1_SCORE > PLAYER_2_SCORE:
      print ('Player 1 wins!')
    elif PLAYER_1_SCORE == PLAYER_2_SCORE:
      print ('Draw!')
    else:
      print ('Player 2')
    play_again = input('Play again?')
  else:
    print('Goodbye!')


main()
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything for your question, but you don't need to do `score = 1` before `self.score = score` - you can just do `self.score = 1` directly.

Comment: What problem are you facing? can you give us some information about the problem you are facing?

Comment: int method player_1. why you are appending function? PLAYER_!_SCORE = question.getscore? instead getscore()?

Comment: Please see how to create [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Theres a lot of code in your question and no clear description of what's going wrong.

Comment: Use a `while` loop inside `main()` because currently, the control will never go to the `Goodbye!` statement

Answer (score 1):

There are different problems:

1. You are missing `self.` inside the `get_score(self)` method.
2. You are not calling the functions.
3. You are trying to modify a global from inside a function.
4. You are not iterating until the user says he wants to end.
5. You are asking each user 10 questions **10 times**.

#### Minimal changes functional code:

```
import random
PLAYER_1_SCORE = 0
PLAYER_2_SCORE = 0
TURN = 0

class Question():
    def __init__(self, question, answer, options):
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        self.options = options
        self.score = 0

    def ask(self,):
        print (self.question + '?')
        for n, option in enumerate(self.options):
            print ('%d) %s' % (n + 1, option))

        choice = int(input())   # answers are integers
        if choice == self.answer:
            self.score = 1
        else:
            self.score = 0

    def get_score(self):
        return self.score

questions = [
  #1
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),
  #1                   
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),
  #3                   
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),
  #4                  
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),
  #5                   
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),
  #6                   
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),
  #7                   
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),

  #8
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),                   
  #9                     
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),
  #10 
    Question(question='How many legs on a horse', 
            answer=4, 
            options=['one', 
                     'two', 
                     'three', 
                     'four', 
                     'five']),
    ]

random.shuffle(questions) 

def player_1():
    for question in questions:
        question.ask()
        global PLAYER_1_SCORE
        PLAYER_1_SCORE += question.get_score()

def player_2():
    for question in questions:
        question.ask()
        global PLAYER_2_SCORE
        PLAYER_2_SCORE += question.get_score()

def game_round():
    player_1()
    player_2()
    global TURN
    TURN += 1

def main():
    play_again = 'Y'
    while play_again == 'Y':
        game_round()
        if PLAYER_1_SCORE > PLAYER_2_SCORE:
            print ('Player 1 wins!')
        elif PLAYER_1_SCORE == PLAYER_2_SCORE:
            print ('Draw!')
        else:
            print ('Player 2 wins!')
        play_again = input('Play again?')
    else:
        print('Goodbye!')


main()
```

#### My approach

```
import random


class Question():
    def __init__(self, question, right, wrong):
        self.question = question
        self.right = right
        self.options = [right] + list(wrong)

    def ask(self):
        random.shuffle(self.options)
        for n, option in enumerate(self.options):
            print ("{}) {}".format(n + 1, option))

        choice = int(input(self.question + "? ")) - 1
        return self.options[choice] == self.right


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.score = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Player {} score:{}>".format(self.name, self.score)


class Game:
    def __init__(self, players, questions):
        self.players = players
        self.questions = questions

    def reset_score(self):
        for player in self.players:
            player.score = 0

    def start(self):
        random.shuffle(self.players)
        for player in self.players:
            print("#"*(len(player.name)+12))
            print("# {}´s turn: #".format(player.name))
            print("#"*(len(player.name)+12))
            print()
            random.shuffle(self.questions)
            for i, question in enumerate(self.questions):
                print("Question #{}:".format(i+1))
                if question.ask():
                    player.score += 1
                print("-"*40)

    def check_winner(self):
        players = sorted(self.players, key=lambda x: x.score, reverse=True)
        top_score = players[0].score
        if players[1].score == top_score:
            print("Draw! {} got the same score.".format(", ".join([player.name for player in players if player.score == top_score])))
        else:
            print("Player {} wins!".format(players[0].name))



questions = [
             Question( #1
                      question='How many legs on a horse', 
                      right='Four', 
                      wrong=(
                             'One',
                             'Two',
                             'Three',
                             'Five',
                             )
                      ),
             Question( #2
                      question='How many legs on a cow', 
                      right='Four', 
                      wrong=(
                             'One',
                             'Two',
                             'Three',
                             'Five',
                             )
                      ),
             Question( #3
                      question='How many legs on a spider', 
                      right='Eight', 
                      wrong=(
                             'Six',
                             'Ten',
                             'Four',
                             )
                      ),
             ]


def main():
    n_players = int(input("How many players are going to play? "))
    if n_players < 2:
        raise ValueError("Minimum of 2 players required")
    players = []
    for i in range(n_players):
        players.append(Player(input("How is player #{} called? ".format(i+1))))
    print()
    game = Game(players, questions)

    play_again = True
    while play_again:
        game.reset_score()
        game.start()
        game.check_winner()
        play_again = input("Play again? ").lower() == 'y'
    else:
        print("Goodbye!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see I created some additional classes, `Player` and `Game`, one holds each player name and score and the other holds a list of questions and players. `Game` has 3 methods. `reset_score()` sets all scores to 0 so that a new game can be played. `start()` shuffles the players, for each player it shuffles the questions and ask them to the player. If the answer is correct his score gets modified. `check_winner()` sorts the players by score and checks if there is a draw. It prints the results. `Question` now needs the question phrase, the right answer and a sequence of wrong answers. When the method `ask()` gets called it suffles the right and wrong answers and prints them. It returns `True` if the answer is correct and `False` if it's wrong.

The part inside the main function is asking for the number of users and their names in order to create the `Player` instances and then creates a game with the players and the questions. A loop is then started that resets the score, asks the questions and checks the winner, just before asking if another round wants to be played. Both `y` and `Y` are valid options.